# Error showing data from firebase to ionic

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic-framework

I want to display data from this console.log and i have a error.

[image]

> Error is: Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

This is part of the code:

```
this.dbFire.database.ref('found').orderByChild('author_email')
            .equalTo(this.email)
            .once('value')
            .then(snapshot => snapshot.val())
            .then((data) => {
                this.getUserPosts = data;

                console.log(this.getUserPosts);
            });
```

Thank you !

Comment: bro what you have got is a object..if you want to use *NgFor make it a array

Comment: How cand i do this?
Thanks bro!

Comment: which version of angular you are using..?

Comment: Ionic version: 3.20.0

Answer (score 0):

```
// declare variable as empty array
getUserPosts: any[] = [];

this.dbFire.database.ref('found').orderByChild('author_email').equalTo(this.email).once('value')
    .then(snapshot => snapshot.val())
    .then((data) => {
        // push data
        this.getUserPosts.push(data);
        console.log(this.getUserPosts);
    });

<li * ngFor="let user of getUserPosts" >
    {{ user.author_email}}
</li>
```

Comment: Thank you, Edison!
Now it's array, but i can't showing.
New console.log: [link](https://imgur.com/a/7WvGDQG)